# The structure of "From A to B, to C, and to D?

Tags: sentence-construction

I think there are two models for **From A to B, to C, and to D** in English, but which one is correct:
[image]

For example, this sentence:

> Models also differ in the approach for representing processes, from empirical models that are based on regression equations, to analytical models that use differential equations to provide a continuous or semi-continuous representation of processes, to models based on energy and mass conservation approaches.

How to understand its structure?

Comment: What system or phenomenon are you trying to model? With what kind of model? For what purpose? Why is your chosen type of model appropriate? The passage you cite enumerates categories of **mathematical** models—would your question be better suited elsewhere in SE? What is English-language about it? Wherever it belongs, it needs more context.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum I think you’re misreading the use of ‘model’ in the question. It’s just meant as a way to say that there are two different possible ways to understand the grammatical construction _from A to B, to C(,) and to D_. The fact that the example quoted also happens to be about (mathematical) models is coincidental.

Comment: Yes, I think this use of the word "model" in a question about "Models" is confusing. I don't think that many people would talk about the model for a sentence in English. I suspect this is the result of the OP having a limited but technical vocabulary.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes. You are my confidant.

Comment: @JamesK  May you tell me if not use "model" in English, what words should be used?

Comment: maybe "meanings" or "interpretations"

Answer (score 5):

I don't really understand what your pictures are meant to show.  The sentence just describes a "spectrum" of different approaches.  A simpler example

> There are different colours in the rainbow: from red, to green, to blue.

The given sentence has the same structure:

> Models also differ in the approach for representing processes:
>
> - from empirical models that are based on regression equations,
> - to analytical models that use differential equations to provide a continuous or semi-continuous representation of processes,
> - to models based on energy and mass conservation approaches.

It is just a list of three points on a spectrum.

Comment: So, A, B, C and D are in parallel?  If express as progressive, how should we write it?

Comment: Use "and", perhaps with while:  "While baking the cookies, make tea, clean the dishes and set the table."

Comment: @Y.zeng or possibly "then" - [for example](https://www.advantagenews.com/news/local/new-co2-pipeline-proposed-in-central-illinois/article_06a4f440-4347-11ee-8ba8-57c6ce9a42ac.html): "The pipeline would originate in Iowa, travel through the Quad Cities, then near Peoria, then on to Decatur."

Comment: Regarding what the pictures show: In the actual sentence quoted in the question, there is no literal, spatial _from > to_,  so it doesn’t make sense to distinguish between the two meanings indicated by the illustrations. But if it’s spatial, the difference is clear: “You can fly from Chicago to New York, to Miami(,) and to Los Angeles” is ambiguous: can you fly Chicago → New York → Miami → Los Angeles (first picture), or can you fly Chicago → New York, Chicago → Miami and Chicago → Los Angeles (second picture)?

Comment: "Fly from Chicago to New York, to Mami, to Los Angeles" means "Chicago → New York → Miami → Los Angeles" or "Chicago → New York, Chicago → Miami and Chicago → Los Angeles"? @JanusBahsJacquet

Comment: @Y.zeng It can mean both. It’s ambiguous.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet In Chinese, there are always such ambibuous expressions. Unexpectedly, the same is true for English.

Comment: What? this is a surprise?  Every natural language is riddled with ambiguity.  English has both sematic ambiguity (where a single word can have multiple meanings) and syntactic ambiguity (where a sentence can be parsed in different ways).  It is just the same as Chinese and every other language in the way.

Answer (score 2):

There are roughly two options for this construction, indicated by context. Though the usage of “from” and “to” alone doesn’t indicate which is in use, I would not consider these ambiguous in almost all cases, since

1. If you are talking about things that are sequential, ordered, have steps, etc., then it will (probably) be A→B→C→D, as in your first suggestion. Very common for routes, where the things are places you intend to visit.

   For example, “I am going from home, to the store, to the gas station, to the library” indicates that I’m starting at home, then going to the store, then going to the gas station, and then going to the library, in that order.
2. If you are talking about a collection, a set, various alternatives, etc., then it will (probably) be (A, B, C, D), without any particular relation between these. (So if I was drawing a diagram like yours, it would be the four boxes inside a circle, with no arrows between them.) This construction is usually used with a non-exhaustive list of *examples*, especially if those examples are near the “edges” or “limits” of whatever they’re an example of, so that the examples serve to plot a vague “bounding box” on the subject in question.

   For example, “The town has many destinations, from houses, to the store, to the gas station, to the library,” there is no sense of order to this. Houses, the store, the gas station, and the library are just places you could go to in the town. They are almost-certainly *not* the only places you could go to in the town, but it gives you an idea of the scope of the place. It suggests a small town, with mostly just services for residents. You wouldn’t expect a wonder of the world in this town.

This construction would not be used to describe something like your second option. To describe a situation like that, an English speaker would be more likely to say something like “some variety of A, such as B, C, or D” or “from A, we have several options, such as B, C, or D,” something like that.

Anyway, as for your example text, I know nothing about the models being discussed in your quote, but the meaning there is that empirical data, differential equations, and energy and mass approximations are three examples of “approaches” that may differ among models. There is no direct relationship between them. Ideally, however, these examples seem to have been chosen to demonstrate the breadth of the field, that all of these different approaches are all considered valid.